# Javascript - target all html selects, not by ID or class

Tags: javascript

I need to inject a new option in to the top of every `<select>` that appears in my forms. So far I have been able to do it in specific forms using

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Please Select";
    x.add(option, x[0]);
}
```

The problem is that I need it for every form and every `<select>` so can't specify in my code an ID. Is there are replacement for getElementById that would target all selects irrespective of their class or id?

Comment: [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)

Comment: 1. IDs need to be unique. 2. `document.querySelectorAll("select");`

Answer (score 2):

[document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is probably is what you are looking for

You could then do something like

```
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
```

Comment: Probably not a good idea to name it `selectArray` as it's definitely not an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getElementsByTagName()` method

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT");

for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = "Please Select";
  x[i].appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<select></select>

<select></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **document.getElementsByTagName("select")** ,this will provide a collection of all select elements

```js
 
var allSelect =  document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for(var i=0;i<allSelect.length;i++){
  
    var x = allSelect[i];
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Please Select";

    /** to make this selected by default we have to set attribute value **/
    var att = document.createAttribute("selected");  
    att.value = "selected";
    option.setAttributeNode(att);
    x.add(option, x[0]);
  }
```

```html
<form id="test">
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Actually, this only seems to work when there's one select in the page. On a page where there are multiple it doesn't run at all. Any ideas?

Comment: create  this as  method and call once the page is loaded, you can also console.log the allselect variable to see how many select elements are in that